# Convert a dataframe to a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table **pandas DF** which looks like

|  | Slave | start_addr0 | end_addr0 | start_addr1 | end_addr1 | start_addr2 | end_addr2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 10000000 | 1FFFFFFF | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | 20000000 | 2007FFFF | 40000000 | 40005FFF | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | 20000000 | 2007FFFF | 20100000 | 201FFFFF | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 2 | 20200000 | 202FFFFF | 20080000 | 20085FFF | 40006000 | 400FFFFF |
| 4 | 3 | 0 | 0FFFFFFF | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | 4 | 20300000 | 203FFFFF | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 6 | 5 | 20400000 | 204FFFFF | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

For each slave number I need to convert it to a list of ranges (tuples). For example,

```py
Slave1_list = ( (20000000, 2007FFFF), (40000000, 40005FFF), (20100000, 201FFFFF))
```

The number of slaves (rows) and address-pairs (columns) can vary.

Thanks

**EDIT**:

Run the following code to load sample data into dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

f = io.StringIO('''Slave|start_addr0|end_addr0|start_addr1|end_addr1|start_addr2|end_addr2
0|10000000|1FFFFFFF|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN
1|20000000|2007FFFF|40000000|40005FFF|NaN|NaN
1|20000000|2007FFFF|20100000|201FFFFF|NaN|NaN
2|20200000|202FFFFF|20080000|20085FFF|40006000|400FFFFF
3|0|0FFFFFFF|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN
4|20300000|203FFFFF|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN
5|20400000|204FFFFF|NaN|NaN|NaN|NaN
''')
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', engine='python', index_col=None)
```

Comment: Can you post a df which we can `copy and run`. Secondly, give the exact expected output for that dataframe. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

One option via `wide_to_long`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
result = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['start_addr', 'end_addr'], i=['index', 'Slave'], j='add_num', sep='').dropna(
).reset_index([0, -1], drop=True).apply(tuple, 1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

An option via `groupby`:

```
k = df.set_index('Slave').stack().reset_index()
result = k.groupby(k.index//2).agg({'Slave': 'first', 0 : tuple}).groupby('Slave').agg({0 : set})
```

**Explanation**:

`df.set_index('Slave').stack().reset_index()` will remove the `NaN` values and stack the dataframe.

`k.groupby(k.index//2)` will group alternate rows and perform the required aggregations(tuples are formed in this step)

`.groupby('Slave').agg({0 : set})` -> Last groupby is to capture the unique tuples for each slave.

OUTPUT:

```
                                                                            0
Slave                                                                        
0                                                      {(10000000, 1FFFFFFF)}
1      {(40000000.0, 40005FFF), (20100000.0, 201FFFFF), (20000000, 2007FFFF)}
2      {(20080000.0, 20085FFF), (40006000.0, 400FFFFF), (20200000, 202FFFFF)}
3                                                             {(0, 0FFFFFFF)}
4                                                      {(20300000, 203FFFFF)}
5                                                      {(20400000, 204FFFFF)}
```

**NOTE:** I'm assuming for every `start_addr` there exists an `end_addr`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'Slave': 1, 'start_addr0': 12, 'end_addr0': 189, 'start_addr1': 9, 'end_addr1': 17},
        {'Slave': 1, 'start_addr0': 3, 'end_addr0': 6, 'start_addr1': 1, 'end_addr1': 4},
        {'Slave': 3, 'start_addr0': 1, 'end_addr0': 7, 'start_addr1': 2, 'end_addr1': 14}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
result = defaultdict(list)
rows = df.to_dict(orient='records')
for row in rows:
    slave = row.get('Slave')
    for key, start_value in row.items():
        if key.startswith('start_addr'):
            idx = key[-1]
            end_value = row.get('end_addr' + idx)
            result[slave].append((start_value, end_value))
        else:
            continue

print('result:')
print(result)
```

output

```
   Slave  start_addr0  end_addr0  start_addr1  end_addr1
0      1           12        189            9         17
1      1            3          6            1          4
2      3            1          7            2         14
result:
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [(12, 189), (9, 17), (3, 6), (1, 4)], 3: [(1, 7), (2, 14)]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def make_tuples(x):
    return tuple([x['start_addr0'], x['end_addr0']])

# simple tuples
result = tuple(df[['start_addr0', 'end_addr0']].apply(make_tuples, axis=1).tolist())
print(result)

# unique tuples
unique_result = tuple(df[['start_addr0', 'end_addr0']].apply(make_tuples, axis=1).unique().tolist())
print(unique_result)
```

---

Output

```
((10000000, '1FFFFFFF'), (20000000, '2007FFFF'), (20000000, '2007FFFF'), (20200000, '202FFFFF'), (0, '0FFFFFFF'), (20300000, '203FFFFF'), (20400000, '204FFFFF'))
((10000000, '1FFFFFFF'), (20000000, '2007FFFF'), (20200000, '202FFFFF'), (0, '0FFFFFFF'), (20300000, '203FFFFF'), (20400000, '204FFFFF'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    var1=dd.iloc[:,1:].unstack().dropna().to_frame('col1')\
        .reset_index().assign(col2=lambda 
           x:x.level_0.str[-1:]+x.level_1.astype('str'))\
        .groupby('col2').col1.agg(tuple).tolist()
    print(var1)

df1.groupby('Slave').apply(function1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(
    df
    .set_index('Slave')
    .pipe(lambda d: 
        d
        .groupby(d.columns.map(lambda x: x[-1:]), axis=1)
        .apply(lambda x: x.apply(tuple, axis=1))
        .stack()
        .loc[lambda s: s.map(lambda x: pd.notnull(x[0]))]
    )
    .groupby('Slave')
    .apply(list)
)
```

output

```
Slave
0                                                    [(10000000, 1FFFFFFF)]
1    [(20000000, 2007FFFF), (40000000.0, 40005FFF), (20100000.0, 201FFFFF)]
2    [(20200000, 202FFFFF), (20080000.0, 20085FFF), (40006000.0, 400FFFFF)]
3                                                           [(0, 0FFFFFFF)]
4                                                    [(20300000, 203FFFFF)]
5                                                    [(20400000, 204FFFFF)]
```

Comment: this does not really answer the question : a list of tuples is required. this is a list of list of tuples.